# NH3 simple summaries

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

Currently I'm playing with NH3 and it's great for really simple things. 
When it comes to less simple we're lost.

I'm creating sample movie database.
I want to display every Movie entity with count of genres that is
associated with movie.
The output list should look like this:

### MovieId | Title | Premiere | Genres Count

3  | bla bla    | 1990-01-01    | 2

Using SQL it would look like this:

```
select f.*, isnull(fg.counter, 0) as genres_count
from dbo.movie f left join
(
select id_movie, count(id_genre) as counter
from dbo.movie_genres
group by id_movie
) fg on f.id = fg.id_movie
```

As you see this is really simple summary SQL.

Now aggregation that counts genres for every movie using QueryOver:

```
GenreSummary alias = null;
var genresQuery = QueryOver.Of<MovieGenre>()
.SelectList(lista => lista
.SelectGroup(o => o.Film.Id).WithAlias(() => alias.MovieId)
.SelectCount(o => o.Genre).WithAlias(() => alias.GenresCount))
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<GenreSummary>());
```

Movie Query:

```
var movieQuery = QueryOver.Of<Movie>().ToList();
```

So now how to join genresQuery with movieQuery to create summary
entity list let's say MovieSummary (MovieSummary has additional column GenresCount)?
Can it be done with QueryOver? 
Can it be done in NH3?

--
Regards,
 Macko

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a few months old now, but I was looking for something similar and came up with a solution.

In my scenario I have a type Parent which has a single child of type Child and a collection called OtherChildren of type AnotherChild.  My summary has the Id and Name properties of the Parent, the Name of the Child and the count of the OtherChildren collection.

IIUC your Movie object has a collection of MovieGenres and you want a summary which has some information about the movie plus the count of its genres.  I think this is similar to selecting Parent Name and count of OtherChildren into a summary object.

This worked for me:

```
ParentSummary parentSummary = null;
Child child = null;
IList<AnotherChild> otherChildren = null;

var result = session.QueryOver<Parent>()
  .JoinAlias(x => x.Child, () => child)
  .JoinAlias(x => x.OtherChildren, () => otherChildren)
  .SelectList(list => list
      .SelectGroup(x => x.Id).WithAlias(() => parentSummary.Id)
      .SelectGroup(x => x.Name).WithAlias(() => parentSummary.Name)
      .SelectGroup(() => child.Name).WithAlias(() => parentSummary.ChildName)
      .SelectCount(x => x.OtherChildren).WithAlias(() => parentSummary.OtherChildrenCount))
  .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ParentSummary>())
  .List<ParentSummary>();
```